# How to include multiple cursor.execute in python

Tags: python, sql-server, cursor

Like I have to take source,ID and destination from sql table but they are present in two different table, so I have tried with

```
dom_id=[1,10,19,31,37,42,48,57,63,64,65]

for i in range(len(dom_id)):
  cursor.execute("SELECT xval, yval from table1 WHERE DOMID=?",dom_id[i])
  source=""
  for row in cursor.fetchall():
      source=float(row[0]),float(row[1])
      source=','.join(map(str, source))
  cursor.execute("select t1.id as pid,pxval,pyval from table2")
  ID=[]
  destination=""
  for row_d in cursor.fetchall():
        ID.append(row_d[0]) 
        destination = float(row_d[1]),float(row_d[2])
        destination = ','.join(map(str, destination))
```

Right now I'm using **for-loop** to extract source and other **for-loop** to extract `ID` and `destination`
I tried with

```
cursor.execute(("SELECT xval, yval from table1 WHERE DOMID=?",dom_id[i]);("select t1.id as pid,pxval,pyval from table2 t1 left join (select * from table3 where clubid=?) t2 on t1.id=t2.pid where t1.cityid in (SELECT cityid FROM table1 WHERE domid = ? group by cityid) and t1.pxval>0 and t2.distance is null order by pid",(dom_id[i],dom_id[i])))
```

but it gives error
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Is there any way I can combine the two `cursor.execute` in a single for-loop.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done like this:

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT a.xval, a.yval,b.pid,pxval,b.pyval from table1 as a,
           (select t1.id as pid,pxval,pyval from <tbl1> t1 
           left join ( select * from <tbl2> where clubid="+clubid+") 
           t2 on t1.id=t2.projectid where t1.cityid in ( SELECT cityid 
           FROM <tbl3> WHERE cbdid ="+cbdid+" group by cityid) 
           and t1.pxval>0 and t2.distance is null order by projectid)
           as b WHERE a.DOMID="+dom_id[i]+"

cursor.execute(sqlQuery)
```

This will give required data from both the table.

NOTE: If both tables has different row count then tell will be NULL values you can check for that using some condition in your code.

If you want to add this on a single execute, try this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT a.xval, a.yval,b.pid,b.pxval,b.pyval from table1 as a, (select t1.id as pid,pxval,pyval from table2 t1 left join (select * from table3 where clubid=?) t2 on t1.id=t2.pid where t1.cityid in (SELECT cityid FROM table1 WHERE domid = ? group by cityid) and t1.pxval>0 and t2.distance is null order by pid) as b WHERE a.DOMID=?",dom_id[i],dom_id[i],dom_id[i])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the second sql query is quite big and already include inner queries in it i.e `select t1.id as pid,pxval,pyval 
from 
    <tbl1> t1 
    left join 
    (
        select * 
        from <tbl2> 
        where clubid=? 
    ) t2 
        on t1.id=t2.projectid 
where 
    t1.cityid in (
            SELECT cityid 
            FROM <tbl3> 
            WHERE cbdid =? 
            group by cityid) 
    and 
    t1.pxval>0 
    and 
    t2.distance is null 
order by projectid`

Comment: The length of the query doesn't matter here. You just have to adjust your dynamic variables correctly.

Comment: Here is the second query `
    cursor.execute("select t1.id as pid,pxval,pyval from table2 t1 left join (select * from table3 where clubid=?) t2 on t1.id=t2.pid where t1.cityid in (SELECT cityid FROM table1 WHERE domid = ? group by cityid) and t1.pxval>0 and t2.distance is null order by pid",(dom_id[i],dom_id[i]))`

Comment: Remove cbid and clubid from above and add dom_id[i] it will get you the results. Also, you can do an exhaustive join to accomodate these two queries into one.

Comment: Editied my answer. Please check.

Comment: I used your code but it gave error `TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.`

Comment: I have added extra brackets I guess at the starting and ending of execute. Please correct it. I have corrected that in my answer.

Comment: Now gave error `ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified. (1033) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

Comment: Remove order by pid inside the nested query and check.

Comment: Instead add order by b.pid at the end of the query after where a.domid=? Order by b.pid

Comment: You're Welcome :)